# Get a unicode string from a QString in python

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside

I am trying to get a unicode string out of a QString with PySide:

```
In [63]: qs = QString("órgão")

In [64]: qs
Out[64]: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'\xc3\xb3rg\xc3\xa3o')

In [65]: print(unic)
unichr   unicode  

In [65]: print(unicode(qs))
Ã³rgÃ£o
```

But it looks the string comes out different then the original. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I have asked a stupid question again, it should be

```
QString(u"órgão")
```

then everything goes ok.